# Mysql: Update table with values from a table in another database

Tags: mysql, database

I accidentally deleted all values in a column of a table in my database. The table contains tracks, and added_by is a string specifying who added the track.

I have now restored an old backup of the database as `old_database` with the table `old_tracks`.
The current version is called `database` and the table is `tracks`.

I would like to restore the values of each addedby field, but this doesn't work out for me:

```
UPDATE tracks  
SET added_by = `old_database`.`old_tracks`.`added_by` 
WHERE id = `old_database`.`old_tracks`.`id`;
```

Can you help me do it the right way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***prc.user :***

> id_user : 45 | name_user : Test | login_user : test | pwd_user : test

***prc_test.user***

> id_user : 45 | name_user : Test | login_user : test | pwd_user : test

***sample query:***

```
UPDATE 
  prc.user, 
  prc_test.user 
SET 
  prc_test.user.pwd_user = prc.user.pwd_user
WHERE 
  prc_test.user.name_user = prc.user.name_user
```

Comment: Hi.. In your answer it is two different tables. But I have the tables in two different databases.

Comment: are the databases in the same mysql server? Or do they reside on different servers?

Comment: The sample query worked. I just used "database.table.column" instead of just "table.column" used in this answer. Thanks.

Comment: @user3368477, (+1) for question, because you tried your self and useful question,..